# Creating a list from another lists Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe.

```
my_list= [(343, 4364), (221, 791), (221, 2847), (21, 1296)]
```

from this list I would like to pick the second value from the list values and get the following list.

```
new_list = [4364, 791, 2847, 1296]
```

Can any one help on this?

Comment: Is the criteria always to get the second element of the tuple for each element in the list?

Comment: Yes. I would like to get the second element.

Comment: `new_list = [i[1] for i in my_list]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing are just `list`s not `pandas DataFrame`s. In order to get the second element, the easiest solution is probably to use list comprehension:

```
my_list= [(343, 4364), (221, 791), (221, 2847), (21, 1296)]
new_list = [x for _, x in my_list]
# or
new_list = [x[1] for x in my_list]
```

If you are indeed working with `pandas`, you can use `[]` to get desired column:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([(343, 4364), (221, 791), (221, 2847), (21, 1296)])
col = df[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

use this snippets:

```
my_list= [(343, 4364), (221, 791), (221, 2847), (21, 1296)]
res=[]
for i,x in my_list:
    res.append(x)

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[4364, 791, 2847, 1296]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with list comprehension:

```py
my_list= [(343, 4364), (221, 791), (221, 2847), (21, 1296)]
new_list = [i[1] for i in my_list]
print(new_list)
```